# How far can python go?

Tags: python, system32

I've started python a few months ago, for school projects and I was pretty surprised at the file edition power it had without asking for **any** permissions. My question is, how far can python go? Can it delete System files? Can it delete normal files? I also saw a video that I didn't click that said python malware was really easy to make... So I am just really curious to how far it goes, mostly because my IDE didn't even need admin permissions to be installed...
P-S: not sure if this is appropriate to stack overflow, kinda new here :)

Comment: Python doesn't impose any restrictions at all. The restrictions are imposed by the OS, based on the user that is running Python (or any other program). As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python can go just as far as the user running Python can. If you have the right to delete a file, then if you start Python and run a script or issue a command that deletes a file, Python will be allowed to. Python will be acting under your user account.

Having said that, it's not always obvious what user is running Python exactly. Normally, if you start Python yourself and pass it a script, or run some commands interactively, it'll be you.

But if, for example, you start Python from a scheduled task, the user running Python won't be you by default, but some sort of system account which may have more restricted rights.

On the other hand, if you're *not* allowed to do something (say access a folder that has restricted access for other users only), you can still write a Python script that tries to perform the actions. If you were to run that script, it would fail, but if one of those other users logs on and runs the same script, it will succeed.

Python is restricted in that it doesn't contain libraries for every function imaginable (although you could probably write them yourself in Python, given enough time). To get around that, you typically install third party packages, created by people that have already written that code, further extending what Python can do. But no package should be able to get around the restrictions the OS imposes on the user running Python.

To get a sense of how complete Python is, even without third party packages, have a look at the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/). All those things can be done with standard Python, provided the user running it is allowed to.